# Android issue in startActivity - opening Activity of parent module instead of library module

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-library

I have one Android project with **main module app** with **one library module app2**.

```
app (com.main.mod)
  -app2 (com.lib.mod)
```

I have imported library module app2 in **build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
implementation project(path: ':app2')
```

I have LoginActivity in both modules -

```
com.main.mod.LoginActivity (app module)
com.lib.mod.LoginActivity (app2 module)
```

I want to start the **LoginActivity of the library app module** but startActivity opens **LoginActivity of main app module**.

```
var intent = Intent(this, Class.forName("com.lib.mod.LoginActivity"))
startActivity(intent)
```

Why does this happen? How can we correct this?
Do let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Regardless of which module this is, it appears as though you have access to the right `LoginActivity` to be able to refer to it directly (`Intent(this, com.lib.mod.LoginActivity::class.java)`).

Comment: Found the issue. Both the LoginActivity had XML layout had the same name. I changed the name of one of the layouts, it worked fine after that. But I don't know why having same names was the problem. Do you have any idea ? @CommonsWare

Comment: Resources are merged when building an APK. It is very important, if you are going to have multiple modules, to ensure that you keep their resources separate, such as by using prefixes (e.g., `lib_activity_login.xml` to distinguish the `lib` module layout from `activity_login.xml` of the `app` module).